# Is there any way to make array json object display in HTML elements by using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

NOT able to display json object data on table.

JSON

```
{"json1":"[{\"years\":2018},{\"years\":2017},{\"years\":2016},{\"years\":2015}]",
"json2":"[{\"year5\":47.5100,\"year4\":50.9300,\"year3\":68.3700,\"year2\":65.2500,\"year1\":0.0000,
\"reportFormula\":\" Total cost of sales/total sales \",\"reportRang\":\"<35%\",\"reportTypeDetail\":\"Cost of sales % of sales\"},
```

```js
let app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  let result = {
    data: {
      "json1": "[{\"years\":2018},{\"years\":2017},{\"years\":2016},{\"years\":2015}]",
      "json2": "[{\"year5\":47.5100,\"year4\":50.9300,\"year3\":68.3700,\"year2\":65.2500,\"year1\":0.0000,\"reportFormula\":\"Total cost of sales/total sales\",\"reportRang\":\"<35%\",\"reportTypeDetail\":\"Cost of sales % of sales\"}]"
    }
  }

  $scope.yearList = result.data.json1;
  $scope.dataList = result.data.json2;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table>
    <th ng-repeat="year in yearList[0].years"> {{year}}</th>
    <th ng-repeat="year in yearList[0].years"> {{year}}</th>

    <tr ng-repeat="data in dataList">
      <td>{{data.reportTypeDetail}}</td>
      <td>{{data.reportFormula}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I've removed the [tag:java] tag; since Java does not appear to be involved in any way.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: There was no error on the code i wasnt able to display my data in my table and i got the solution thanks @Thanthu

Comment: @Minh I posted a solution based on your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two mayor issues with your code. First, remember the golden rule: "Always parse your **JSON** object".

**Why I need to parse my JSON?** Well, when using the `JSON.parse()` on a **JSON** derived from an array, the method will return a JavaScript array, instead of a JavaScript object.

**But what this means?**
It means that *JSON* objects is represented as a JSON string which JavaScript cannot read directly.

**Ok, then how can I parse it?**
The Syntax is very simple `JSON.parse(text)`, where `text` is the string to parse as JSON and it will return the Object corresponding to the given JSON text.

#### The `ng-if` directive and `$index` attribute

Now, you are using the following code to define your `<th>` tags:

```
<th ng-repeat="year in yearList[0].years"> {{year}}</th>
```

Which I think it is not correct, and limits your control of the values.

I think a better solution is if you combine the `ng-repeat`'s `$index` attribute with the `ng-if` directive. Like this:

```
<th ng-repeat="year in yearList" ng-if="$index == 0"> {{year.years}}</th>
```

This will give you more control of the values and how you want to show them. This the working code for those modifications:

```js
let app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  let result = {
    data: {
      "json1": "[{\"years\":2018},{\"years\":2017},{\"years\":2016},{\"years\":2015}]",
      "json2": "[{\"year5\":47.5100,\"year4\":50.9300,\"year3\":68.3700,\"year2\":65.2500,\"year1\":0.0000,\"reportFormula\":\"Total cost of sales/total sales\",\"reportRang\":\"<35%\",\"reportTypeDetail\":\"Cost of sales % of sales\"}]"
    }
  }

  $scope.yearList = JSON.parse(result.data.json1);
  $scope.dataList = JSON.parse(result.data.json2);

  console.log('yearList', $scope.yearList);
  console.log('dataList', $scope.dataList);
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table>
    <th ng-repeat="year in yearList" ng-if="$index == 0"> {{year.years}}</th>
    <th ng-repeat="year in yearList" ng-if="$index == 1"> {{year.years}}</th>


    <tr ng-repeat="data in dataList">
      <td>{{data.reportTypeDetail}}</td>
      <td>{{data.reportFormula}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON object contains two stringified json objects which JavaScript cannot directly read. To parse them use JSON.parse() like this:

JSON

```
{"json1":"[{\"years\":2018},{\"years\":2017},{\"years\":2016},{\"years\":2015}]",
"json2":"[{\"year5\":47.5100,\"year4\":50.9300,\"year3\":68.3700,\"year2\":65.2500,\"year1\":0.0000,
\"reportFormula\":\" Total cost of sales/total sales \",\"reportRang\":\"<35%\",\"reportTypeDetail\":\"Cost of sales % of sales\"},
```

JS

```
$scope.yearList=JSON.parse(result.data.json1);
$scope.dataList=JSON.parse(result.data.json2);
```

HTML

```
<th   ng-repeat="year in yearList[0].years">{{year}}</th>
<th   ng-repeat="year in yearList[1].years">{{year}}</th>
...
<tr ng-repeat="operation in dataList">
<td>{{operation.reportTypeDetail}}</td>
<td>{{operation.reportFormula}}</td>
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are using yearList[0] in your ng-repeat which returns an object like the following,

```
{"years":2018}
```

you can use

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in yearList[0]">
    {{key}},{{ value }}
</div>
```

to loop through your object or you can try the following to display the data from your list.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in yearList">{{item.years}}</div>
<br>
<div ng-repeat="operation in dataList">
  {{operation.reportTypeDetail}}<br>
  {{operation.reportFormula}}
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QrRCBy1ucYKibI5xD6QV)**